# Combine two arrays into an array by performing an operation for each pair of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are two arrays having same length:

```
firstArray = [22, 54, 33, 10];
secondArray = [2, 27, 11, 10];
```

I want to get a third array as result by dividing each element of the first one to its pair in the second one, in this case the result should be:

```
resultArray = [11, 2, 3, 1];
```

I tried to do it using `foreach()` and `map()` but all I get is undefined values. For example this code:

```
firstArray.forEach(index) => {
    resultArray[index] = firstArray[index] / secondArray[index];
});
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `index` is the second parameter. Do `.forEach((_, index)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the result of iteration of `firstArray` and take the value of `secondArray` with an index.

```js
var firstArray = [22, 54, 33, 10],
    secondArray = [2, 27, 11, 10],
    result = firstArray.map((v , i) => v / secondArray[i]);
    
console.log(result);
```

Another solution, could be to collect all arrays in an array and reduce the data.

```js
var firstArray = [22, 54, 33, 10],
    secondArray = [2, 27, 11, 10],
    result = [firstArray, secondArray].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v , i) => v / b[i]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try like that :

```
firstArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    resultArray[index] = item / secondArray[index];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way seems to be :

```js
var firstArray = [22, 54, 33, 10],
secondArray = [2, 27, 11, 10];
var resultArray = firstArray.map( (e, i) => e / secondArray[i]);
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using function `reduce`

```js
var firstArray = [22, 54, 33, 10],
    secondArray = [2, 27, 11, 10],
    thirdArray = firstArray.reduce((a, n, i) => { a[i] = n / secondArray[i]; return a}, []);
    
console.log(thirdArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```